# Polling Battery Drain

Tags: javascript, cordova, polling

I'd like to know how much polling will drain battery life. Is it dependent on the message size? Or is just the fact that I'm polling at all that makes it drain the batter?

I can provide more details:

Polling once every two seconds, and the message length is 60 bytes (on average)

Comment: Depends entirely on what hardware you're running on, what you're polling, how often, over what… in short, it's impossible to give a general answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has very little to do with the message size, much to do with frequency.

Every time you poll, the phone must use its network - basically, its radio. If you send a large message, it may use the radio for slightly longer (but probably not enough to matter). If you're sending incredibly large messages, this will start to have a larger impact - but you aren't polling incredibly large messages, right?

However, polling frequently - even small messages - causes *severe* battery drains in phones. Different phones respond differently... be particularly careful with Android, which in some hardware/software combinations will allow you to poll even when backgrounded.

We had good success (also building in HTML5) by detecting interaction with the page (all touch events) and gradually delaying our polls when the page had been untouched for some time. Eg, ontouch, poll = 3s. Next poll = 4s. Next poll = 5s... and so on.

Comment: Do you know the comparison between battery draining and sockets?

Comment: In our experience (lots of empirical testing but nothing scientific), we found that websockets on phones is pretty awful for the battery for two reasons: one, if the nature of the interaction is long - like a video game - the cell radio is running that entire time. With polling, you can at least manage the balance between responsiveness and battery drain by changing your polling interval. The other type of interaction - phone out, glance, back in pocket - is even worse because the socket connection is expensive to recreate and check over and over.

Comment: That's the exact answer I was looking for. Thanks a ton. Now that phonegap build comes integrate with push I may explore that option too.

Comment: Yeah if you're wrapping in phonegap I would go with the push option. I would also mark this question as answered ;)